# Execute action upon window resize with devilspie2

Tags: xubuntu, devilspie

I'm looking for a devilspie2 alternative that can handle more window events, like "on resize". Right now there's only open and close window events.

For example, I would like to undecorate a window only if it's maximized.

```
if (get_application_name() == "myapp") then
    if (get_window_is_maximized() == true) then
        undecorate_window()
    else
        decorate_window()
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

### An alternative

Given that your example to to undecorate the window when maximized but redecorate when it is not maximized, in this answer I've taken the liberty to promote "maximus"

Tested on xubuntu 14.04, by installing maximum via:

```
sudo apt-get install maximus
```

All subsequent windows that you open are automatically undecorated, but after unmaximizing, they are redecorated.

During my testing, this constant automatic maximizing was annoying.  Thus to fix the automatic maximization issue use this option:

```
gconftool -s /apps/maximus/no_maximize true -t bool
```

Lets show this in action when using both maximus and the gconftool tweak:

[image]

I like keyboard shortcuts - so a quick tip - to toggle between maximized windows and not maximised, remember the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>

Comment: nice! one little problem, windows are starting maximized (like I want) and I have to toggle (the maximized status) so maximus remove the decorations.. any idea why?

Comment: Thunar and xfce4-terminal works just fine but Firefox, Transmission and a few others aren't gettting undecorated (but are starting maximized). Firefox unmaximized => quit => next time I open it will work. Now I restart Firefox, it doesn't get undecorated, only maximized.

Comment: ok - looks like this answer is only applicable with the gconf toggle - you need to start the application window first before maximising.  This looks like a bug in maximus.  You've got 6 days - hopefully someone will post another answer that works with your "start maximized" scenario.